# How do I find $\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}$ for this equation?

Tags: calculus

Find $\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}$ given $ x^3+y^3=1$

How do I differentiate this equation? 
Do I differentiate by have y be y x dy/dx?

Comment: Can anyone tell me if this is correct? I found dy/dx=x^2/y^2 then using the quotient rule found the derivative of dy/dx= 2x(y^3+x^3)/y^5

Answer (score 2):

You have two choices:  you can solve for $y$, getting $y=(1-x^3)^{\frac 13}$, and differentiate twice.  I believe that is what you are expected to do.  Alternately you can differentiate implicitly, using $\frac d{dx}y^3=3y^2\frac {dy}{dx}$, then differentiate again.  It looks like this gets you into a mess.

Answer (score 0):

I get via implicit differentiation:

$$ \frac{d^2y}{dx^2} = -\frac{6x}{3y^2} - \frac{2x^4}{y^5}.  $$ Please verify.

Cheers,

Paul Safier